# jquery populating wrong input on back button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am seeing a bit of a strange issue on webkit browsers where when I click the back button, my search input gets populated with the values which are meant for another input below generate by jQuery slider.

script in the doc ready

```
    $(function() {
        $( "#slider-amount" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 50000,
            values: [ 4000, 30000 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( "€" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - €" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            }
        });
        $( "#amount" ).val( "€" + $( "#slider-amount" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
            " - €" + $( "#slider-amount" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
    });
```

Search input:

```
            <input id="topminiSearch" type="text" value=""/>
```

Input slider

```
                <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
                <div id="slider-amount"></div>
```

Comment: yes, cleared cache, I have the issue on multiple devices and webkit browsers

Comment: Have you tried giving both input elements a name attribute?

Comment: yes that seemed to have fixed it, always something simple. Thanks. If you post it as an answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried giving both input elements a name attribute?